# Como descobrir a estrangeira de uma tabela para outra pelo Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle11c

Quando estamos executando instruções SQL e que precisamos navegar entre as tabelas fica simples quando conhecemos a modelagem do banco de dados para aplicar `JOIN` e `GROUP BY`, porém quando não conhecemos, o que fazer? É necessário aplicando `DESC`Tabela nas tabelas para saber quais são as chaves estrangeiras?

Existe algum comando no oracle que nos mostre as chaves estrangeiras entre as tabelas?

esse seria a forma;

```
select f.table_name, t.table_name, t.column_name, f.constraint_name, t.owner
from all_cons_columns t, all_constraints f
where f.r_owner = t.owner
 and f.table_name = 'PARCELAMENTO'
 and f.r_owner='root';
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143728/how-can-i-find-which-tables-reference-a-given-table-in-oracle-sql-developer

Answer (score 2):

Com esse select você pode ver as tabelas pais e filhas

```
select f.table_name, t.table_name, t.column_name, f.constraint_name, t.owner
from all_cons_columns t, all_constraints f
where f.r_owner = t.owner
and f.r_constraint_name = t.constraint_name
```

Se você procura de uma tabela especifica você pode realizar pode acrescentar o filtro:

```
and  f.table_name = 'sua_tabela'
```

Comment: se eu quiser de uma tabela especifica o final vai ficar assim f.table_name = parcelamento; o nome da tabela é parcelamento.

Comment: ficaria:  and  f.table_name = 'PARCELAMENTO'

Comment: não é essa instrução sql porque no meu resultado retornou 50 mil registros, mas minha tabela somente tem 6 chaves estrangeiras.

Comment: acrescente no filtro and f.r_owner='SEU_USUARIO'

Comment: dá uma olhada na minha postagem, acabei de atualiza, e dessa forma, se for dessa forma não está me retornando nada.

Comment: Você precisa colocar o nome do usuário em letra maiúscula